# How to create Model based C# List from Database

Tags: entity-framework, relational-database, generic-list

I have Models created through Entity Framework as:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Then another Details Table:

```
 public partial class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderItemsID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

 To See the Master Detail Data I made MasterDetails model As:

 public class OrderVM
{
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to make a method that return a LIST with Join query results but 
   I'm receiving #Anonymous type error here is my Code:

```
public static List<OrderVM > mylist()
    {
        List<OrderVM> slist = new List<OrderVM>();

        using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
        {
            var myvalues = from O in dc.Orders
                          join D in dc.OrderDetails
                          on
                          O.OrderID equals D.OrderID
                          select new
                           {
                               O.OrderID,
                               O.OrderDate,
                               D.Quantity,
                               D.Rate
                           };


              foreach(var myorders in myvalues)
              {
                  slist.Add(myorders);
              }

              return slist;


        }
    }
```

I need a help that how I can I create a generic list with database fields

Answer (score 0):

Create new class:

```
public class OrderDetailsModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

and return list of objects of this class from your method:

```
    using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
    {
        var myvalues = from O in dc.Orders
                      join D in dc.OrderDetails
                      on
                      O.OrderID equals D.OrderID
                      select new OrderDetailsModel
                      {
                          OrderId = O.OrderID,
                          OrderDate = O.OrderDate,
                          Quantity = D.Quantity,
                          Rate = D.Rate
                      };


          return myvalues.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help